# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset

Tags: java, deep-learning, weka

I am trying to install a deep learning package in weka but every time I try to install this error appears
how can I solve it
https://deeplearning.cms.waikato.ac.nz/
[PackageURL]https://github.com/Waikato/wekaDeeplearning4j/releases/download/v1.6.0/wekaDeeplearning4j-1.6.0.zip

**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.downloadArchive(DefaultPackageManager.java:218)
    at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.installPackageFromURL(DefaultPackageManager.java:768)
    at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.installPackageFromRepository(DefaultPackageManager.java:753)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.installPackageFromRepository(WekaPackageManager.java:2294)
    at weka.gui.PackageManager$InstallTask.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:1437)
    at weka.gui.PackageManager$InstallTask.doInBackground(PackageManager.java:882)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(Unknown Source)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is just bad internet conection. I solve it , Thanks